# Could this variable be modeled by a poisson regression?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, glmm, poisson-regression

I have a pc experiment and an ordered response variable with 8 levels (from 0 to 7). I have also a factor (different types of stimuli) to include as a predictor in the model. So in each trial, the subject could respond from 0 to 7 to the stimulus and then I have the following distribution:

[image]:

Where `x` represents levels of the variable and `y` the relative frequency.

Both theoretically and empirically this seems to me a Poisson distribution so I've tried to fit a GLMM with `lme4`

```r
glmer(Test_Memory ~ Emotion * Memory + (1|Subject), family = "poisson", data = data)
```

The random factor is for dealing with non-independent observation (repeated measure design).
I'm not an expert if GLMs and non-normal distributions so I'm wondering if this could be a good approach. In particular, if the variable could be modeled in this way or if I should use another regression model.

Comment: I don't think Poisson regression works well with bounded responses, especially when the bounds are observed in the data. If you think this is close to a measured scale binomial GLMs might not be too far of a stretch. Otherwise consider ordinal logit or probit (cf. @Peter Flom - Reinstate Monica.

Answer (score 0):

Poisson is usually used for response variables that are counts.

You say that your response is "ordered" and the usual method there is ordinal logistic regression.

There are some differences:

1. When you have a count, then only non-negative integers are possible, even in theory. You can't own 1.25 cars. When you have an ordinal response, you could be in-between (say) "good" and "excellent".
2. With a count, the idea of multiplying the response variable is sensible. Two cars is twice as many cars as one car. With an ordinal response, this is not so. "Excellent" is not twice as good as "good".
3. The models make different assumptions. Poisson regression assumes that the mean equals the variance. With an ordinal response "mean" and "variance" don't (technically) make any sense, but the usual ordinal logistic model assumes proportional odds.

Comment: Poisson regression can work well with non-negative responses beyond counts. The log-linear element turns out to be more crucial than the variance structure, and even then there are standard ways of getting more honest inferences. But I agree: I would not reach for it in this thread.